# Meaning of "I'm a large"

Tags: expressions

In one of the Seinfeld episodes (season 6, episode 12) there is a conversation, in which Elaine tells Jerry that she had given a label maker to a dentist and the dentist obviously gave that same label maker to Jerry, also as a gift.

[image: Seinfeld series fragment]

At the end, Jerry says "If you're getting him anything for his birthday, I'm a large".

What does "I'm a large" mean?

Comment: It means his shirt size is large, as opposed to medium, small, extra-large, etc.

Comment: It means "My shirt size is _Large_". He's suggesting that if he's going to eventually get whatever she gives the dentist, she might as well get a shirt in Jerry's size.

Comment: 'I am a (size) large', meaning 'I wear a (size) large'.

Comment: There's not much new under the sun. This question [was asked a year ago](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20315/im-a-large-seinfeld) over on English Language Learners. Personally I think it's General Reference for ELU.

Comment: Jerry's problem is that he appears not to acknowledge that he is — at most — a medium.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Literally, he means his shirt size is "large (L)". In context, as mentioned in a comment, he  is telling her to buy a large shirt or whatever, just in case the dentist decides to give it away (to him).